# Element Reveal at Scrolling down within a Range

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have coded using jquery and css to reveal my **contact form** while I scrolling down the page. But I tried to set a range of element display while scrolling. At this time I have only setup the scrolling down and hiding part. Need to develop code for Display this object within 200px - 1024px range only.

Anyone have idea for this. Please send me an answer.

**Please see this animated gif**: https://gph.is/2RpQrOp OR https://ibb.co/6y7wCmK

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (1600 > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("sticky").style.top = "200px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("sticky").style.top = "-1000px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
/* Test contact-sticky*/

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  transition: top 0.3s;
  top: -1000px;
  left: 827px;
  right: 46px;
  background-color: #ebc11d;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<p class="sticky">Contact form</p>
```

Comment: Couldn't you change `if (1600 > currentScrollPos)` to `if (200 < currentScrollPos && 1024 > currentScrollPos )` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with your markup and css.

1. You are expecting ID to be there in contact form. `document.getElementById("sticky")` But there isn't one. Either add ID there or get it from class using `getElementByClassName`
2. Have proper offset defined. For this snippet to work, I had to set 200 as offset. If you are planning to support multiple resolution, then it is better to get complete document length and then subtract some 200px and use it as offset.
3. Do not have conflicting changes between in-line and stylesheet styles.  `document.getElementById("sticky").style.top` changes in-line styling where as `top: -1000px;` is defined from stylesheet.

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
if (10 < currentScrollPos && 210 > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("sticky").style.top = "0px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("sticky").style.top = "-1000px";
  }
window.onscroll = function() {
  currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (10 < currentScrollPos && 210 > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("sticky").style.top = "000px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("sticky").style.top = "-1000px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
/* Test contact-sticky*/

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  transition: top 0.3s;
  background-color: #ebc11d;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<p class="sticky" id="sticky">Contact form</p>
```

Comment: Thank you @Prajwal. for your answer. I got your point. Actually I need to see this form within a range of scrolling. When I scroll down after 200px, the **contact form** must be shown and I visited near footer this **contact form** must be hidden.( without covering footer contents)

Comment: Well, you just need to change this if condition `if (10 < currentScrollPos)`

Comment: I am trying to do this. I couldn't be successful. Can you help me o this please?

Comment: I've updated the answer. `210px` is what I'm assuming where you want it to be removed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had used wrong code. Now everything work fine. This is the **Best Answer**